# Pausing Bootstrap carousel When a Video playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have multiple slide with videos and images. Carousel is set to autoplay when loaded. But when someone plays a video and move mouse out of the side it keeps sliding ( as expected ).

**How do I keep track of when a video is playing and pause?** I have search around Stack Overflow but didn't find similar question.

Site admin will add video later on so they could be iframe or html5 video. So, I need a solution that works for both.

Comment: How is the video embedded in the HTML?

Comment: Via iframe embed (youtube, vimoeo etc) or html5 video.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked for me to pause the Bootstrap carousel when a native HTML5 video is playing and play it again when a video is paused or done playing. I'm a total JS novice but I searched around and strung a few things together. I may have made a mistake (likely) but it works for me.

I am not calling videos by IDs because I want the action to work on any video playing in the carousel. I have a few in my case.

Note to change the ID of the carousel to match yours.

```
<script>
$('video').on('play', function (e) {
    $("#portfolioCarousel").carousel('pause');
});
$('video').on('stop pause ended', function (e) {
    $("#portfolioCarousel").carousel();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

$("#myCarousel").carousel('pause');
to stop it
$("#myCarousel").carousel();
to start it again
http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html
there many events you should start it again even pause, ended events are fired and pause on play.

for youtube im not sure about how you integrate it but they do have js api so 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events
will show you events that you can listen and do same as u did with html5 video

Answer (score 2):

For Youtube iframe videos to trigger a pause on the sliding of the carousel whenever a video is playing, you need to have an indicator on whether a video is considered "playing". You can achieve this by using the player functionalities of the Youtube iframe API with JavaScript.

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference
- https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_status
- https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events

Listen to events that involves these states:

- YT.PlayerState.PLAYING
- YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING

And then control the Bootstrap carousel sliding through `.carousel('pause')` :

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/#methods

To be able to listen to such events, you can add to your JavaScript a function called "onPlayerStateChange" (as described within the Youtube iframe API):

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) // triggered everytime ANY iframe video player among the "players" list is played, paused, ended, etc.
{
    // Check if any iframe video is being played (or is currently buffering to be played)
    // Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING || event.data == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING)
    {
        // If any player has been detected to be currently playing or buffering, pause the carousel from sliding
        // .carousel('pause') - Stops the carousel from cycling through items.
        // Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/#methods
        $('#moviesCarousel').carousel('pause');
    }
    else
    {
        // If there are no currently playing nor buffering videos, resume the sliding of the carousel
        // This means that once the current video is in a state that is not playing (aside from buffering so either it was paused, or has ended, or wasn't totally played), then the carousel would now resume sliding
        $('#moviesCarousel').carousel();
    }
}
```

For reference, here is the full working HTML (works directly, no modifications needed) :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Buttons for manually sliding the carousel -->
    <div class="btn-group col-lg-8" role="group" aria-label="Carousel controls">
        <button id="prevMovie" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Prev</button>
        <button id="nextMovie" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Next</button>
    </div>

    <!-- The carousel containing the Youtube iframe videos -->
    <!-- Remember to add the ?enablejsapi=1 in the Youtube embed link as described in: -->
    <!-- https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Example_Video_Player_Constructors -->
    <div id="moviesCarousel" class="carousel slide col-lg-8" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
        <div class="carousel-inner embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"> <!-- embed is used for responsive size regardless of device -->
            <div class="carousel-item embed-responsive-item active">
                <iframe id="katniss" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/v98Rh9qzmPs?enablejsapi=1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item embed-responsive-item">
                <iframe id="rancho" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-MlkASchodc?enablejsapi=1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item embed-responsive-item">
                <iframe id="logan" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UgJr0bNmTL8?enablejsapi=1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            // Slide the carousel upon button click
            // .carousel('prev') - Cycles to the previous item
            // .carousel('next') - Cycles to the next item.
            // Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/#methods
            $('#prevMovie').on('click', function() {
                $('#moviesCarousel').carousel('prev');
            });
            $('#nextMovie').on('click', function() {
                $('#moviesCarousel').carousel('next');
            });

            // When a slide occurs, pause the current iframe video that is playing
            // player.pauseVideo():Void - Pauses the currently playing video.
            // Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls
            $('#moviesCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(event) {
                // The variable "players" contain each Youtube Player for each iframe video
                // Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player
                // event.from - The index of the current video (before the slide occurs)
                //            - It is also the index of the corresponding player for the current video
                // Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/#events
                players[event.from].pauseVideo();
            });
        });

        // Start of snippet from: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
        var players = []; // would contain 1 player for each iframe video
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
        {
            var allMovieIframes = document.getElementById("moviesCarousel").getElementsByTagName('iframe');
            for (currentIFrame of allMovieIframes)
            {
                players.push(new YT.Player(
                    currentIFrame.id, // the target iframe video, here it is  either katniss, rancho, or logan
                    { events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange } }
                ));
            }
        }
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) // triggered everytime ANY iframe video player among the "players" list is played, paused, ended, etc.
        {
            // Check if any iframe video is being played (or is currently buffering to be played)
            // Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING || event.data == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING)
            {
                // If any player has been detected to be currently playing or buffering, pause the carousel from sliding
                // .carousel('pause') - Stops the carousel from cycling through items.
                // Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/#methods
                $('#moviesCarousel').carousel('pause');
            }
            else
            {
                // If there are no currently playing nor buffering videos, resume the sliding of the carousel
                // This means that once the current video is in a state that is not playing (aside from buffering so either it was paused, or has ended, or wasn't totally played), then the carousel would now resume sliding
                $('#moviesCarousel').carousel();
            }
        }
        // End of snippet from Youtube iframe API
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```